# Are there better estimators of misclassification error than the fraction of misclassified test points?

Tags: classification, estimation, binomial-distribution, prediction, error

Assume we train a binary classification model using the training set. Also assume that the model returns an estimate of the probability of success $\hat f(x)$ for every feature vector $x$ and was trained with "an intent of" minimizing out of sample cross-entropy error (maximizing likelihood). Moreover, assume we actually picked the algorithm based on the training data (but never looked at the test data), so we don't trust cross-validation (because training data can't be "unseen" by researcher who created an algorithm to train $\hat f$).

We are interested in the estimation of the out of sample misclassification error $E_{out} = P((\hat f(x) \geq 0.5) \neq y)$. The commonly used approach is to interpret the number of misclassified points $n_{\text{test,misclassified}}$ in the test set as an observation of a binomial random variable with probability $p = E_{out}$ and number of trials $n = n_{\text{test}}$ (number of points in the test set). Then the classical estimate would be $\hat E_{out} = n_{\text{test,misclassified}} / n_{\text{test}}$. This gives an estimator with 0 bias but potentially high variance (if the test set is small). We may want to use additional knowlede we have to reduce the variance. We have e.g.:

1. Test and training sets,
2. Estimated probabilities $\hat f(x)$.

Are there any commonly occurring situations where we can leverage any additional knowledge to provide a better estimate of misclassification error?

Comment: Not trusting cross validation would seem to imply you have larger issues.

Comment: Why? Cross validation results are only fully trust-able when the training process can isolate arbitrary subset of the data as a test set, which is not the case when the model choice is performed by a researcher looking at the data. No?

Comment: Why should the researcher's choice of model affect the test set? Sepearate your train/test set with a random number generator.

Comment: I'm saying that the test set should best be picked before researcher does exploratory data analysis. Otherwise rigourously speaking test set error can no longer be trusted since the model choice is not independent of the test set.

Comment: If you don't want to use cross-validation because of the effects of "researcher degrees of freedom", then it is difficult to see how "test and training sets" or "estimated probabilities" are likely to be admissible.  Personally, I think I would estimate the posterior distribution of the test error rate (taking into account the uncertainties in the parameter estimates) if you have so little data, as at least that will give an indication of the uncertainty in the estimate of the quantity of interest.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really worried about unaccounted "researcher degrees of freedom", I suspect the best you can do is to automate your model construction procedure (including feature selection, hyper-parameter optimisation etc.), so that the researcher is not making any choices *after* seeing the data.  You can then use cross-validation provided you perform the whole model construction procedure independently in each fold.

In practice, it is often best to simply acknowledge there are unaccounted degrees of freedom, and make an effort not to over-analyse the data.  While AutoML has become a hot topic in machine learning, I suspect "CyborgML", where the operator becomes an implicit and unaccounted part of the machine learning procedure, is likely to be a significant issue for the foreseeable future, especially in Deep Learning, where models are computationally expensive to fit.  This *ought* to be less of a problem for more classical statistics.

Answer (score 0):

$Eout=P((\hat f(x)≥0.5)≠y) $ is rarely used. You're assuming that 0.5 is a useful decision threshold. What if all of $\hat f(x)$ is above 0.5, or all below?

Because $\hat f(x)$ is continuous, you can set this threshold in many different ways. At one, true positive rate is maximized. At the other, false positive rate is maximized. Somewhere in between F1 is maximized. Which is best, really depends on your application.

For classification problems, AUC and Average Precision scores ingrate over *all* decision thresholds to give you a single number.

However these have their own problems (as do TPR and FPR). AUC is a terrible metric when class population size are imbalanced.

But to answer your specific question, which I understood as, how can I evaluate my algorithm without being 'polluted' by train data. Cross validation *is* the gold standard here. You separate the train/test into N non-overlapping pairs of train and test. The trainer never see the test data. You end up with k models and k independent tests.

In the extreme case, you can set the test set size=1, and train on the rest. If you assume this tiny difference in training data has little effect on the model, your test set size can be as large as your training set size (although small test sets aren't suitable for calculating AUC).

Confidence intervals on TPR, FPR, AUC can also be calculated and are useful. See: [binomial CI](https://www.google.com/search?q=binomial%20confidence%20interval=) and [AUC CI](https://www.google.com/search?q=auc%20confidence%20interval)

Comment: Why is AUC terrible when class population is unbalanced?  It is the probability the model scores a random positive class higher than a random negative class, it seems to me it is balance agnostic.

Comment: Well -- I have an Alzheimer model with an AUC of 0.87. Sounds respectable. Is it useful? In this population (which includes a lot of young people. The model derives this AUC mainly from looking at the age feature. Young people rarely get Alzheimer's. Is this a good test for Alzheimer disease? Not really -- here's a couple of sample decision cuts: accuracy=98.8%, tpr=22.9% fpr=1% ppv=2% npv=99.8%. At the other end: accuracy=30%, tpr=98.% fpr=70% ppv=0.01% npv=99.9%.
The AUC is reasonable, but age is *not* a good test for alheimer's

Comment: ppv=2% basically means that if the model says you will get Alzheimer's, it will be right just 2% of the time. :-/  The average precision score for this same model is 0.05. This is a good reflection of the model's poor ppv, across many different FPRs.

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4403252/ -- argues for AP scores where the dataset is imbalanced. "The AUC lacks sensitivity in identifying cases". In my Alzheimer case, the model gets high AUC by (correctly) identifying young people won't get Alzheimer's. But performance for older people, where all the positive cases are, its basically, a crap shoot.

Comment: If you're goal is to identify alzheimers in the older population, why not just leave the young out of the training and testing sets?

Comment: Well... that presupposes some prior knowledge. In many case there may not be a clear which features identify your target cohort, nor is there a clear cutpoint. This also points to additional issues with AUC -- selecting this more relevant older, cohort reveals a harder classification problem and *lower* AUCs. The AUC-maximizing researcher is punished under AUC optimizing peer review processes (:-/).

Comment: But your original statement was "AUC is a terrible metric when class sizes are imbalanced".  Of course the problem is harder if you remove the young data points, as these are the easy ones to classify, but this is a structural problem, not one with the metric.  The issues you discuss are important, but seem to be agnostic to the evaluation metric.

Comment: Fair. But isn't the broader problem is a lack of sensitivity when care very much about the minority class. In my Alzheimer's case I have ~ 500 cases in a population of 350000. Does an AUC 0.87 tell me if my model is working reasonably? All it really says is its a lot better than random. But would you push it to production? What metric would be better?

Comment: Here's another thing that's a little funky about AUC. When using n years of follow-up to determine the model's target variable, AUC is maximized with low n (high imbalance) and minimized with high n (more cases and less imbalance). The opposite is true for AP (low n=low AP, high n=high AP). Its empirically true for all of the diseases I can model.

Comment: "You're assuming that 0.5 is a useful decision threshold." the question would be equally valid for any fixed threshold (that may depend on misclassification costs and/or differences in training set and operational priors).  If misclassification error (or equivalently expected loss) is the quantity of interest to the application, I think it is unhelpful to suggest methods such as AUC that ignore the threshold, which may be the critical difficulty.